# Yoast Generated Page sitemap Error, Contains jQuery Scripts

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, yoast

I have Yoast installed on my website and the `page-sitemap.xml` Generated by Yoast has jQuery Scripts. Is it ok, or not Because `page-sitemap.xml` shows error

**This page contains the following errors:**

**error on line 22 at column 39: xmlParseEntityRef: no name**

**Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

https://www.briotix.com/page-sitemap.xml

I Can't find where the issue. `view-source:https://www.briotix.com/page-sitemap.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Check your jquery on the source of page-sitemap, it makes the sitemap broken. Try to remove or change how you put it in your page template.

Why post-sitemap did not break like the other one? because your posts template didn't contain the jquery script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable all plugins but Yoast and activate the default theme? It can be a conflict or a poorly-coded plugin to interfere.

Even better if you test it on a staging site ;)